# Azure AD B2C: No SLA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

On their web page, there is no SLA for accounts less than 50000 or authentication under 50000.  I understand that why because it is free.  But what if we have small user base but we want SLA?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that why because it is free. But what if we have small user base but we want SLA?

What do you mean about the free? As far as I know, there is no SLA is provided for the Free tier of Azure Active Directory B2C, the SLA describes Microsoft’s commitments for uptime and connectivity. If your B2C can support SLA, you could try this with small users. For the details, you could read [SLA for Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/active-directory-b2c/v1_0/).

Comment: But there technically is no free tier.. :) But the answer is basically correct: `No SLA during the period that the service is available for free. `. So once you start paying for B2C you get the SLA.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but I am still confused.  Pricing page says:

First 50,000 Stored Account/Month =  Free 
First 50,000 Authentication/Month = Free

Clearly, it said there is no SLA during the period that it is free.  If we only have 2000 accounts and never exceeds the 50000 authentication per month, then we would not be paying for anything.

Comment: Now, my managers don't want to use a service that does not have an SLA. I could write a script that runs authenticatication 50K every first day of the month to guarantee that we are paying for something and the SLA kicks in.  

I like free stuff but what we want is to pay for an SLA agreement even during the periods that are usage is below the threshold?

Answer (score 0):

Direct Azure Customer:  There is a free tier available.  But for Enterprise Agreement Customer, there is no Free Tier and SLA is effect when there is no Free Tier.